# How do I stop mathematica from producing weird numerical errors?

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, approximation

I have here a piece of mathematica code:

```
ClearAll[intfy]
mu = 0;
(*Define density functions*)
fx[x_, mu_, sigma2_] := (1/Sqrt[2*Pi*sigma2])*
  E^(-((x - mu)^2)/(2*sigma2))
fy[y_, mu_, sigma2_] := (y^(-2))*fx[1/y, mu, sigma2]

(*Plot density functions. No problem here*)
Manipulate[
 Plot[{fy[x, mu, 1]}, {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
 , {mu, 0, 2}]

(*Numerically find integralsof expectations*)
intfx[mu_, sigma2_] := 
 intfx[mu, sigma2] = 
  NIntegrate[x*fx[x, mu, sigma2], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
intfy[mu_, sigma2_] := 
 intfy[mu, sigma2] = 
  NIntegrate[x^(-1)*fx[x, mu, sigma2], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(* I at first used the followingn for intfy, which theoretically should be the same, but it gives me a different answer, probably for numerical reasons:
intfy[mu_, sigma2_] := 
 intfy[mu, sigma2] = 
  NIntegrate[x*fy[x, mu, sigma2], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
*)    


(*Plot expectations as function of parameters*)
Plot3D[{intfx[mu, sigma2], 1/intfy[mu, sigma2]}, {mu, 0, 10}, {sigma2,
   0, 4}]
sigma2 = 1;
Plot[{intfx[mu, sigma2], 1/intfy[mu, sigma2], intfy[mu, sigma2]}, {mu,
   0, 10}]
```

What this is supposed to do is: given the normal distribution of $X$: $N(mu,sigma2)$, it should plot:
$E(X)$ and $\frac 1 {E(\frac 1 X)}$

However, instead, I get a long list of numerical errors that I don't get:

> [image]

And the graphs are clearly wrong:

> [image]
>
> [image]

**My question is: What should I do to get more reliable numerical estimates?**

Comment: Is your definition for `intfy[mu, sigma2]` correct? You don't use `fy` anywhere.

Comment: @KraZug, I have used the law of the unconscious statistician there. But, if I do it directly, I get a different, but also weird result: https://i.gyazo.com/9e3931422741599efaa0f593df1be82b.png

Comment: @KraZug, In any case, even if I have made a mistake there, my main question still stands, namely, how do I get the function to be more accurately approximated (whether the function itself is the right one or not).

Comment: Well, as the error tells you, the integral diverges at some point. Anything you get after that is highly suspect. What happens as `sigma2` tends to zero in your definitions?

Answer (score 4):

First, your code contains syntax errors, such is `intfx[mu_, sigma2_] :=intfx[mu, sigma2] =NIntegrate[....` . You should omit the intermediate `intfx[mu, sigma2]` and write straight: `intfx[mu_, sigma2_] :=NIntegrate[...`

Second, your second integral diverges, since in the vicinity of the point `x=0` the function under the integral is `~1/x`. So you cannot integrate it directly. You might agree to exclude the point `x=0`. If so, try the following:

```
ClearAll[intfy]
mu = 0;
fx[x_, mu_, sigma2_] := (1/Sqrt[2*Pi*sigma2])*Exp[-((x - mu)^2)/(2*sigma2)];
intfx[mu_, sigma2_] := NIntegrate[x*fx[x, mu, sigma2], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Compiled -> True];
intfy[mu_, sigma2_] := NIntegrate[x^(-1)*fx[x, mu, sigma2], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, Exclusions -> 0, Compiled -> True];

sigma2 = 1;
Plot3D[{intfx[mu, sigma2], 1/intfy[mu, sigma2]}, {mu, 0, 10}, {sigma2,
    0, 4}] // Quiet

Plot[{intfx[mu, sigma2], 1/intfy[mu, sigma2], intfy[mu, sigma2]}, {mu,
    0, 10}] // Quiet
```

Note that I define `sigma2`first, and write the plot operations after, not another way around. This yields

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: I wouldn't call  `intfx[mu_, sigma2_] :=intfx[mu, sigma2]=...` a syntax error, it will store the value for later reuse. Whether that is needed here is questionable, but it isn't a syntax error.

Comment: @KraZug, Yes that is indeed why I did it. It may not be necessary here, but do you think that this has anything to do with the problem I had?

Comment: No, your problem is exactly as Alexei described, that the second integral is singular at `x=0`.

Comment: So let me see if I understand it correctly: If this was not a numerical approximation but an exact one, then it wouldn't matter whether we included 0, is that correct? because the function is undefined at 0 anyway, and moreover, including a measure-zero point or not will not influence the value of the integral. The reason it is failing, is because the numerical approximation is discrete, and therefore including 0 will cause a division by zero in the sum. I still don't fully understand what that would cause this problem, because a division by zero should cause an error, not a wrong result.

Comment: @KraZug, Unless I'm falsely assuming that the expectation $E(1/x)$ even exists? Is this a wrong assumption? If so, then what does excluding the 0 do for us? I'd be approximating something that doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't know the statistics, but Mathematica tries to find the value of the integral, and throws the error to let you know that it has possibly failed to converge. It returns a possible answer as its best guess, but you should treat warning messages like those during evaluation as meaning anything else is suspect unless you know otherwise.

Comment: The actual integral you are doing goes from -$inf$ to $inf$, but has a singularity at $x=0$. Provided you don't try and get too close to 0, you can calculate the two integrals on the domains $(-inf,\delta], [\delta,inf)$ for small $\delta$. But without telling it otherwise, Mathematica will try and get infinitesimally close to 0.